# Can not center button

Tags: css, center

I am trying to center a button. At first sight the buttons seems centered. However when the screen size gets smaller the button is more to the right. I already tried to use text-align: center; etc. But that does not work. I really can not figure out what causing this problem. I had another button container and i have not problems with that one. Below the link to codepen. Solutions are welcome. Thanks.

https://toffewebsite.nl/example.html

Comment: do you want only one button in the middle!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

If you want only one button to be in the center,then use this https://codepen.io/the-wrong-guy/pen/GRoMNmg?editors=1100

Comment: thank you so much.this works fine:

display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;

Still learning. thanks again

Comment: you are welcome,also check the codepen and add the body and all styles in your css

Comment: Hi. I tried the codepen. However then the button is not centered. I just used:


.button-boxpulse {
    
   display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
    
     margin-top: 50px;
}

Instead of:
.button-boxpulse {
    margin-left: 46vw;
     margin-top: 42vh;
    
}

That is working fine. Wondering why the button is not centered in the codepen example.

Comment: well did add the `body` styles in your code and i didn't add any code for `.button-boxpulse`  in my codepen